# Can anyone explain the function of .map()

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, dictionary

I was trying to make a Covid Tracking application using flutter, and I came across this function ***getCountrySummary( )***,

```
import 'package:covid_tracker/models/country_summary.dart';
import 'package:covid_tracker/models/global_summary.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class CovidService {
  Future<GlobalSummaryModel> getGlobalSummary() async {
    final data =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.covid19api.com/summary'));

    if (data.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception();
    }

    GlobalSummaryModel summary =
        GlobalSummaryModel.fromJson(json.decode(data.body));

    return summary;
  }

  Future<List<CountrySummaryModel>> getCountrySummary(String slug) async {
    String url = "https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/$slug";

    final data = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (data.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception();
    }

    List<CountrySummaryModel> summaryList = (json.decode(data.body) as List)
        .map((item) => CountrySummaryModel.fromJson(item))
        .toList();

    return summaryList;
  }
}
```

So I know what the function getCountrySummary() is trying to do, but I don't understand what  statement

```
List<CountrySummaryModel> summaryList = (json.decode(data.body) as List).map((item) => CountrySummaryModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

is trying to do, and CountrySummaryModel is an object.

```
class CountrySummaryModel {
  final String country;
  final int confirmed;
  final int death;
  final int recovered;
  final int active;
  final DateTime date;

  CountrySummaryModel(this.country, this.active, this.confirmed, this.date,
      this.death, this.recovered);

  factory CountrySummaryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CountrySummaryModel(
      json["country"],
      json["active"],
      json["confirmed"],
      DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
      json["death"],
      json["recovered"],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#mapping, also read the whole article to better understand `Iterable`s

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Map` on a list, it means you want to reach each item in it, in your case you call map on your list to parse each item in it and at then call `toList()` to make a list of this items.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly:

1. First, you convert `data` to `List`.
2. Then, use `CountrySummaryModel.fromJson()` and `.toList()` to convert it to `List<CountrySummaryModel>`.